# How to echo from other php file?

Tags: php, html

I have file index.php with form and I want to process the form with other php file. How can I echo the result to get "Hello *name*"?

Here's the code:

```
 <form action="action.php" method="post">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<p>Hello {here goes the name} </p>
```

And other php file:

```
<?php
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['name'];
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: `echo "Hello".$_POST['name'];`

Comment: I strongly recommend not to [name a form element `submit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345107/javascript-submit-is-not-submitting-the-form), but if "other php" is action.php, the code is not showing on the same page as the form - the statement `<p>Hello {here goes the name} </p>` will not work on the same page. But also  [see if there are errors somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: You could likely benefit from using a session variable

Answer (score -1):

You have to put them in the same file in order for this to work or to use AJAX for form submission and some JS.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  Name:<input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  ?>
    <p>Hello <?=$_POST['name']?></p>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't the use of the `action` attribute of the `form` tag to call another page?

Comment: @mplungjan, my understanding of this answer was that you can't call another page with form submission you have to use AJAX.

Comment: Is not XSS complaint but he asked for the solution for a solution to print that variable from post, you can also use `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` but is not a safe solution also

Comment: `<p>Hello <?=$_POST['name']?></p>` is a problem. I can post `name=<script>anything here</script>`

Comment: @AlexandruCorlan or you can leave the action attribute out and not even mention it, it will then also post to the same page.

Comment: You also don't have to put this in the same file for it to work. For example, you submit the form to other.php which uses `header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?name=peter");`. This will redirect you back to index.php setting the variable name as `$_GET['name']`.

Comment: or you can set `$_SESSION['name']` in another file and then use it in index page after redirect... as @mplungjan mentioned in the comments.